# My skin is black and doesnt show up in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have minecraft on andriod but due to the new uptade problem (the no license error) I use toolbox for minecraft and i was playing normally on a server and I closed and opened it yesterday and my skin was black so he chose my default skin,Steve, and I tried to change it but he says "the skin is invalid" so right now I am using Alex but I want to change and I don't know how and also pictures doesn't appear for worlds and player but texture packs works fine but world icons and these texture pack's icon doesn't appear too I don't if its minecraft's problem or the launcher's problem or even my device's problem

I just need some help the pictures won't matter with me as much I only need to change my skin but I can't

(I wanted to add a screenshot but I can't somehow)

Plz I need help I will appreciate it so much

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you could do.

1. Reload the game.
2. Re-upload your skin to the MC launcher.
3. Re-download the skin file.

If those don't work, I don't know what to tell you.